# Como puedo mejorar condicional IF php

Tags: php, condiciones

tengo la siguiente duda:

en mi index.php tengo el siguiente if:

```
$tabla.="
<table>
<tr>";
if($horar > '6:00 am' AND $horar < '6:00 pm')
{
$tabla.="
<td>Día</td>";
}else{
$tabla.="<td>Noche</td>";
}
$tabla.="
</tr>
</table>
```

Mi variable $horar trae la hora en este formato ejemplo: 6:00 am

entonces lo que quiero con ese if es que si $horar esta entre el rango de las 6:00 am y 6:00 pm entonces es turno día de lo contrario seria turno noche.

pero no me funciona correctamente, siempre me dice que es turno noche.

Como podría mejorar ese IF?

Cualquier ayuda seria de gran utilidad muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es `$horar`, una cadena, un objeto `DateTime`?

Comment: Hola, $horar es solo un valor que trae esta información: 6:00 am o puede ser cualquier hora del día.

Comment: No puedes comparar de esa forma cadenas de texto. `$hora` tiene que ser un numero en el rango 0-23 por ejemplo

Comment: Ha ok, si hago que hora sea solo un nro. sera más dificil de saber si es de día o de noche, porque ejemplo: 6 no sabria si son las 6 de la mañana o las 6 de la tarde.

Comment: Entonces tienes que hacerlo como te respondió @A.Cedano , parseando el string a Datetime. Si quieres usar operadores de comparación numéricos (ej: $hora > "1") se usa el rango 0-24 como estándar de hora. Esto está definido en la [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) y varios estándares mas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más seguro en estos casos es trabajar con objeto temporales (`DateTime`), con los cuales podrás calcular fácilmente diferencias y comprobar si el objeto está entre un rango determinado.

Aquí creamos tres objetos: uno que represente el tiempo límite para determinar si es de día, otro que determine el tiempo para marcar la noche y un tercer objeto que es el que recibirías. Luego preguntarás si ese objeto está en el rango de los otros dos.

He aquí un ejemplo con varias pruebas. Para la comparación, he evitado el `if`, asignando el resultado a una variable con un ternario. Hay varias pruebas y al lado el resultado, la línea fundamental es esta en todos los casos:

```
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
```

### Código

```
$mBegin=new DateTime("6:00 am");
$mEnd=new DateTime("6:00 pm");

#Varias pruebas
$mHour=new DateTime("6:00 am"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de día

$mHour=new DateTime("6:01 am"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de día

$mHour=new DateTime("6:00 pm"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de día

$mHour=new DateTime("6:01 pm"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de noche

$mHour=new DateTime("5:00 am"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de noche

$mHour=new DateTime("8:00 pm"); 
$mStatus= ($mHour >= $mBegin && $mHour <= $mEnd) ? "Es de día" : "Es de noche";
echo $mStatus.PHP_EOL; #Es de noche
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias me funciono como lo necesitaba.

Comment: Saludos cordiales